# read file contents to an array

Tags: c#, text, openfiledialog

I have this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream;

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string filetext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);

            richTextBox3.Text = filetext; // reads all text into one text box
        }
    }
}
```

I'm struggling on how to get each line of the text file to a different text box or possibly store it in an array, can some one help please!

Comment: How about using `File.ReadAllLines` instead of `File.ReadAllText`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using dialog.OpenFile and then File.ReadAllText, there is an option for the dialog to verify that the file exists, then just use the ReadAllLines like @JonSkeet said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) will read all of the text in a file.

```
string filetext = File.ReadAllText("The file path");
```

If you want to store each line separately in an array, [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) can do that.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("The file path");
```

Answer (score 2):

Optionally, you can use the following to return a list of strings.  You can then either bind the list of strings directly to the control, or you can iterate through each item in the list and add them that way. See below:

```
public static List<string> GetLines(string filename)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>(); // A list of strings 

    // Create a stream reader object to read a text file.
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        string line = string.Empty; // Contains a single line returned by the stream reader object.

        // While there are lines in the file, read a line into the line variable.
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // If the line is not empty, add it to the list.
            if (line != string.Empty)
            {
                result.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of work versus File.ReadAllLines, plus you can be reasonably assured the framework library has been thoroughly tested. I'd avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Good point!  Well it's another option but the one mentioned by Jon and yourself is obviously the better of the two.